# Crystal Reports: Unkown Database Connector Error

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle11g, crystal-reports-2008

I have Crystal Reports 2008.
I been using it for long time on my Windows 7,
I use it once a week and it always worked but today I don't know why, but I am getting

`Unkown Database Connector Error`

What is the fix for this? looks like I am able to connect to Oracle server via Sql Plus without any problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Problem is Windows 7..

```
You Open Crystal Reports by right click and run as administrator.
```

Good Luck